# De Jonquières formula vs. Relative GW invariants

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, algebraic-curves, gromov-witten-theory, enumerative-geometry, brill-noether

**Background.** Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g$. Denote by $C^d$ its d-th symmetric product and by $G^r_d(C)$ its associated variety
of linear series of type $\mathfrak{g}^r_d$, i.e.
$$ G^r_d(C):= \left \{ \mathcal{L} = (L, V) \: | \: L \in Pic^d(C), V \in G(r + 1, H^0(C, L)) \right \}$$

**Definition.** A linear series $\mathcal{L}$ on $C$ is said to admit a length $n$ de Jonquières divisor if
$$ a_1 p_1 + \ldots + a_n p_n \in \mathbb{P}(V) $$
for some points $p_1,\ldots , p_n \in C$ and some positive integers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ whose sum is $d$.

We call the corresponding divisor 
$$D := p_1 + \ldots + p_n \in C^n$$
a *de Jonquières divisor* of length $n$.

De Jonquières formula (In [ACGH](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387909974) chapter VIII, §5) states that, if we
expect there to be a finite number of de Jonquières divisors of length $n$, then
this virtual number is given by the coefficient of the monomial $t_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot t_n$ in
$$(1 + a_1^2 t_1 + \ldots + a_n^2 t_n)^g(1 + a_1 t_1 + \ldots + a_n t_n)^{d−r−g}.$$
.

**My question.**

1. Why is the virtual count in this formula "wrong"? I heard there are supposed to be some counter-examples showing that the formula does not always give the "correct number", I'm curious to know: (1) what they are, and (2) what then is the formula actually counting...
2. Is there a way to relate the virtual count in this formula to *relative Gromov-Witten invariants* (in the sense of [Li-Ruan](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803036), [Ionel-Parker](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v157-n1-p02.pdf) and [Jun Li](http://www.emis.de/journals/NYJM/JDG/p/2001/57-3-6.pdf)) of $\mathbb{P}^r$ with respect to the curve $C$ embedded by the linear series $\mathcal{L}$ in the cases where it makes sense (i.e. lines/conics/... with prescribed tangencies. An example is the formula for the number tangential trisecant to a given curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ in [ACGH, p.364](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387909974))?

Comment: Standard onomastic use should be "Jonquières formula", "Jonquières divisor", without "de". (If referring to the mathematician, it would be "E. de Jonquières, Ernest de Jonquières, but Jonquières when first name is omitted).

Comment: I'm sure you're grammatically correct, but "De Jonquières" is the monikor under which it is quoted everywhere (including AGCH)... At least that I've seen (I'm happy to be corrected)

Comment: Yes it's a common error, it's indeed quite subtle. In "Jonquières group/transformation" google finds it both with and without "de".

Comment: @YCor: do you also talk about Ligne--Mumford stacks? :)

Comment: @potentiallydense Never heard of "Pierre de Ligne" :) But even if there was such, it would remain "de Ligne" (as "de Gaulle") because one-syllabic.